# discord py, постоянное обновление информации из json

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть команда, которая по api выводит в Embed онлайн сервера.
Могу ли я реализовать такую функцию, чтобы каждую секунду бот обновлял данные из api через *message.edit*?

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="", description=f"Сейчас на сервере **{onl}** из **{max_onl} игроков.**", color = 0x2f3136)
await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

Именно сам обновлял данные, без ввода команды по новой.

Answer (score 1):

Каждую секунду нет, так как [discord rate limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits) не позволят этого, но можно, например каждые 45 секунд через [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Вот пример кога:

```
class Tasks(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.update_message.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.update_message.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=45)
    async def update_message(self):
        channel = discord.utils.get(self.bot.get_guild(айди гильдии).text_channels, id=айди канала)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(айди сообщения)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="", description=f"Сейчас на сервере **{onl}** из **{max_onl} игроков.**", color = 0x2f3136)
        await message.edit(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Tasks(bot))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

Comment: Из ошибки же ясно, что неверный айди либо гильдии, либо айди канала, и для этого есть документация, вы можете от туда посмотреть, что вписывать в методы

Comment: Но почему оно возвращает пустоту...Айдишники я правильные указал 100%.